# Stop Netbeans automatically including missing headers

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have noticed Netbeans 8.2 occasionally includes missing headers for C++ projects. By this I mean Netbeans actually enters 'include' and the file name.  I think this occurs when I compile (within Netbeans). It tries to be smart and detect that I forgot to `include <array>`

and therefore it inserts:

```
#include <c++/4.8.2/array>
```

Is there a way to disable this automatic including of headers?

Comment: Don't know about C++, but for Java this can be configured in Tools -> Options -> Editor -> On Save (there is an option "organize imports" for Java, I could imagine that is equivalent to includes in C/C++)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name instead of "On Save" can you see "Code Completion" and I see "Insert Single Proposals Automatically"?

Answer (score 1):

With `Netbeans 11.2`, try:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Editor` > `Code Completion` > `Language choose C/C++`

Uncheck `"Auto Insert #include ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

Tools->Options->Code Completion->C/C++

then untick "Auto insert #include directives for Completed Identifiers"